# merge 2 xmls into a single with xslt in a mule flow

Tags: xml, xslt, mule

I have a Mule flow that is attempting to merge 2 xmls into a single xml to be passed as a payload to a rest api call. 
xml1 --

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ProviderInformation>
  <Provider_Name>
    <FirstName/>
    <LastName/>
    <Title/>
    </Provider_Name>
    <DBA>
      <Using_DBA/>
      <DBA_Name/>
      <Years_DBA/>
      <Months_DBA/>
      <Using_Former_DBA/>
      <Former_DBA_Name/>
      <Years_Former_DBA/>
    </DBA>
    <TIN>
    <SSN/>
    <Using_EIN/>
    <EIN/>
    <NPI/>
    <Ownership_Type/>
    <Gender/>
    <DOB/>
    <Provider_Email_Address/>
    <Provider_Email_Address_Verify/>
    <Practice_Website_Address/>
    </TIN>     
 </ProviderInformation>
```

xml2 --

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Medicare>
    <Enrolled_In_Medicaid/>
    <Medicare_ID/>
    <Medicare_NPI/>
    <Medicare_Enrollment_Date></Medicare_Enrollment_Date>
 <Using_Other_Medicaid_CHIP/>
    <Other_Medicaid_ID state="SC">
      <Other_Medicaid_ID/>
      <Other_Medicaid_NPI/>
      <Other_medicaid_Effective_Date></Other_medicaid_Effective_Date>
        <Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date></Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_State/>
    </Other_Medicaid_ID>
    <Other_Medicaid_ID state="GA">
      <Other_Medicaid_ID/>
      <Other_Medicaid_NPI/>
      <Other_medicaid_Effective_Date></Other_medicaid_Effective_Date>
         <Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date></Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_State/>
    </Other_Medicaid_ID>
</Medicare>
```

output --

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT-Application>
  <ProviderInformation>
  <Provider_Name>
    <FirstName/>
    <LastName/>
    <Title/>
    </Provider_Name>
    <DBA>
      <Using_DBA/>
      <DBA_Name/>
      <Years_DBA/>
      <Months_DBA/>
      <Using_Former_DBA/>
      <Former_DBA_Name/>
      <Years_Former_DBA/>
    </DBA>
    <TIN>
    <SSN/>
    <Using_EIN/>
    <EIN/>
    <NPI/>
    <Ownership_Type/>
    <Gender/>
    <DOB/>
    <Provider_Email_Address/>
    <Provider_Email_Address_Verify/>
    <Practice_Website_Address/>
    </TIN>
</ProviderInformation>
   <Medicare>
    <Enrolled_In_Medicaid/>
    <Medicare_ID/>
    <Medicare_NPI/>
    <Medicare_Enrollment_Date></Medicare_Enrollment_Date>
 <Using_Other_Medicaid_CHIP/>
    <Other_Medicaid_ID state="SC">
      <Other_Medicaid_ID/>
      <Other_Medicaid_NPI/>
      <Other_medicaid_Effective_Date></Other_medicaid_Effective_Date>
       <Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date></Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_State/>
    </Other_Medicaid_ID>
    <Other_Medicaid_ID state="GA">
      <Other_Medicaid_ID/>
      <Other_Medicaid_NPI/>
      <Other_medicaid_Effective_Date></Other_medicaid_Effective_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date></Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_State/>
    </Other_Medicaid_ID>
   </Medicare>
</ROOT-Application>
```

I think one way of doing it is using xslt.
Can someone pls help me with the xslt file as I am not able to create it. Or is there any other way to do this in a mule flow without using xslt ?

Comment: "*Can someone pls help me with the xslt file as I am not able to create it.*" We are here to help you with your coding - not to do it for you.

Comment: where is your Mule flow ? let us see how these 2 xml payload are coming into your flow .. Pls share your Mule config

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps:-
1.Parse the **XML1** with [XPATH3](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/) and store all the node values in variables like the following :-

```
<set-variable variableName="FirstName" value="#[xpath3('//ProviderInformation/Provider_Name/FirstName')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="LastName" value="#[xpath3('//ProviderInformation/Provider_Name/LastName')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

.... and so on

2. Do the same for **XML2**, and store all the node value in variables :

`<set-variable variableName="Medicare_ID" value="#[xpath3('//Medicare/Enrolled_In_Medicaid/Medicare_ID')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
 <set-variable variableName="Medicare_NPI" value="#[xpath3('//Medicare/Enrolled_In_Medicaid/Medicare_NPI')]" doc:name="Variable"/>`

and so on till you extract and store all the values in variables.

3. Now in your Mule flow put the XSLT transformer and pass the variable values to your XSLT like the following :-

`<mulexml:xslt-transformer name="mergeXml" xsl-file="Transform.xsl" outputEncoding="UTF-8"  encoding="UTF-8" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="XSLT">
    <mulexml:context-property key="FirstName" value="#[flowVars.FirstName]"/> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
    <mulexml:context-property key="LastName" value="#[flowVars.LastName]"/> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
    <mulexml:context-property key="Medicare_ID" value="#[flowVars.Medicare_ID]"/> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
    <mulexml:context-property key="Medicare_NPI" value="#[flowVars.Medicare_NPI]"/> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
 </mulexml:xslt-transformer>`

Please note, you need to pass all the variables that you have used to store the **extracted** value.. Here I have shown you only 4 as an example ....

Now, in your Transform.xsl :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <!-- Getting values from Mule variables -->
   <xsl:param name="FirstName"/>
   <xsl:param name="LastName"/>
   <xsl:param name="Medicare_ID"/>
   <xsl:param name="Medicare_NPI"/>
  <!-- Add all the variables  -->
<xsl:template match="/">
 <ROOT-Application>
  <ProviderInformation>
  <Provider_Name>
    <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="$FirstName"/></FirstName>
    <LastName><xsl:value-of select="$LastName"/></LastName>
    <Title/>
    </Provider_Name>
    <DBA>
      <Using_DBA/>
      <DBA_Name/>
      <Years_DBA/>
      <Months_DBA/>
      <Using_Former_DBA/>
      <Former_DBA_Name/>
      <Years_Former_DBA/>
    </DBA>
    <TIN>
    <SSN/>
    <Using_EIN/>
    <EIN/>
    <NPI/>
    <Ownership_Type/>
    <Gender/>
    <DOB/>
    <Provider_Email_Address/>
    <Provider_Email_Address_Verify/>
    <Practice_Website_Address/>
    </TIN>
</ProviderInformation>
   <Medicare>
    <Enrolled_In_Medicaid/>
    <Medicare_ID><xsl:value-of select="$Medicare_ID"/></Medicare_ID>
    <Medicare_NPI><xsl:value-of select="$Medicare_NPI"/></Medicare_NPI>
    <Medicare_Enrollment_Date></Medicare_Enrollment_Date>
    <Using_Other_Medicaid_CHIP/>
    <Other_Medicaid_ID state="SC">
      <Other_Medicaid_ID/>
      <Other_Medicaid_NPI/>
      <Other_medicaid_Effective_Date></Other_medicaid_Effective_Date>
       <Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date></Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_State/>
    </Other_Medicaid_ID>
    <Other_Medicaid_ID state="GA">
      <Other_Medicaid_ID/>
      <Other_Medicaid_NPI/>
      <Other_medicaid_Effective_Date></Other_medicaid_Effective_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date></Other_Medicaid_Enrollment_Date>
      <Other_Medicaid_State/>
    </Other_Medicaid_ID>
   </Medicare>
</ROOT-Application>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note that you need to fill all the node values from the variables.. I have only shown you just 4 variables ( FirstName,LastName, Medicare_ID, Medicare_NPI ) here as an example.
This will merge both your **XML** togather with values

Answer (score 0):

Try using xsl:copy-of.
Like this --

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <!-- Getting values from Mule variables -->
    <xsl:param name="xml1" />
    <xsl:param name="xml2" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ROOT-Application>  
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="document($xml1)" />
       <xsl:copy-of select="document($xml2)" /> 
      </xsl:copy>
      </ROOT-Application>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```